# Maven behind a auto-generated proxy

Tags: maven, proxy

I'm behind a auto-generated proxy.

I've configured my settings.xml to use this proxy, but it 
still doesn't work. The Android SDK works fine with the
same proxy which I've set.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <host>MY-PROXY-HOST-HERE</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

What else can I do to make maven to work?

Error:

```
WARNING: NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authenti
cation: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCr
edentials
```

How to get my NTLM authentication credintals?

---

```
Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authorization Required.
```

This is the output message. In my wpad.dat (from where I've taken proxy data), I don't have a specified username and password...

Comment: What do you mean by `, but it still doesn't work.`? Error messages? Some kind of output ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

credentials are not the solution!

Solution to your problem is [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

steps to go

**First step -->**

**Steps to get rid of these NTLM proxy Issues permanently.**

1. download and install [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)
2. edit cntlm.ini file in cntlm installation directory and make sure there is proxy of your network i.e. "Proxy NTLMPROXYHOST:PORT" e.g. Proxy 192.168.0.1:8080 (this is your network proxy from which you access internet!)
3. DO NOT FORGET TO PUT your windows authentication credentials in cntlm.ini file just put your windows username ,your domain name ,your password .
4. create environment variable(system variable) named CYGWIN with value "nodosfilewarning"(without quotes) if you don't do so you are not able to even start cntlm! Secondly make two environment variables named `http_proxy` with value "`http://localhost:3128`" and `https_proxy` with value "`http://localhost:3128`".
5. go to start menu and click on cntlm folder then click on "start cntlm authentication proxy"(DO NOT FORGET TO MAKE "start cntlm authentication proxy" SHORTCUT A STARTUP PROGRAM OTHERWISE YOU CAN NOT ACCESS INTERNET AFTER REBOOT!! OR YOU NEED TO MANNUALLY START CNTLM PROXY EVERY TIME YOU REBOOT!!).
6. open internet explorer --> Tools --> Internet Options --> Connections --> LAN settings
7. tick mark both the checkbox under "proxy server" heading.
8. put localhost or 127.0.0.1 in "address" text box and put 3128 under "port" text box(yes! you do not need your network proxy anymore as we already kept in cntlm.ini).
9. click ok then again ok then close IE.

Thats it!! now you never see error related to NTLM proxy authentication failed or anything else not even in sbt or maven!!! CNTLM is quite fast as it is developed in C !!

**Second step -->**

start cntlm authentication proxy server

make sure your settings.xml file's proxy look like this.

```
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>127.0.0.1</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Plese give me feedback if something does not work!

Comment: Ctnlm works great for the most time. But it has occasional hangs and crashes (Windows 7) and does not seem to be updated anymore. An alternative would be great.

Comment: NOTE: If you use Cntlm DO NOT leave blank <username></username> and <password></password> in the maven proxy settings. It won't work. Instead remove those lines entirely like in this answer.

Comment: If your proxy requires authentication, the configuration within the cntlm.ini becomes tricky and I would recommend to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962313/7066647). It saved my day as I hadn't included the option `Auth`.

Answer (score 8):

I've found a working solution on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ugbandula/post/how-to-configure-maven-to-work-with-ntlm-proxies). You simply put a `wagon-http-lightweight` jar into Maven `lib/ext` folder.

Comment: Thanks faced the same above issue. Resolved once I copied it from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.2/wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar. Thanks again!