# ant Ivy behind corporate proxy

Tags: ant, proxy, ivy

I am trying to run an ant script behind a corporate proxy and I can't seam to get it to work :
i have followed what I presume is the closest to what I have :
http://www.midvision.com/community/code-blog-for-developers/bid/275503/Allow-access-from-Ivy-to-the-internet-through-a-corporate-firewall-that-requires-authentication

And I still get `Your proxy requires authentication` message.
I have some specia characters inside my password and I escaped them with url encodings.

I am new to Ivy and I am trying to build Apache nutch . An y idea what could be the problem? I am using the latest ant and ivy versions (1.9.4 and 2.4.0).

Comment: I would try changing to a password without special characters for a start, to eliminate that variable.

Comment: In the end I ended up  using a free server on koding.com and compiled it there and downloaded it through an a simple http-server. If I encounter another problem and I cannot use an external server .I will return to this question and maybe provide fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose to use Nexus or Artifactory. Yes, getting through a firewall is not their purpose, but it protects you from the repository going down and stopping your development.  I use Nexus and getting through the firewall was a snap.

Comment: So nexus supports correct proxying and I could add a  local nexus repository to the ivy repo list and it will act as a proxy in fact ?

Comment: I set Nexus as a resolver in ivy settings.  It already has Maven Central as a repository and I have added springframework as an example.  All I had to do is set the proxy info in the settings just like I would with Firefox.  It holds onto copies of the JARs that we use and gets through the proxy to get new ones it hasn't gotten yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use CNTLM software and put proxy of its local server. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348) answer for detailed steps