# cntlm error: Too many open files

Tags: c, networking, configuration, proxy, linux-mint

As the title says i have got some issues with Cntlm. I'm working with the 0.92.3 version and launched from the source code. What i am trying to do is starting Cntlm as a standalone proxy with localhost configuration, to browse internet and launch applications (e.g. Skype).

I am working on Mint and the command `uname -a` gives:

```
Linux Jarvis 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Those are the steps i did before asking:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

everything goes fine. I also export http, https and ftp proxy with:

```
export http_proxy = http://127.0.0.1:3128 
export https_proxy = https://127.0.0.1:3128 
export ftp_proxy = https://127.0.0.1:3128
```

and also everything goes fine. What remains is to launch cntlm, doing with:

```
sudo cntlm -v -f
```

it keeps information passed by *cntlm.conf* correctly, and display it's staying in the foreground.

I go in my browser (firefox) and configure it for the proxy, setting 127.0.0.1 as http proxy and 3128 as the port.

when i launch a browser tab a do a test research under the proxy, the terminal starts to elaborate data, but after a few seconds it keeps saying that:

```
cntlm[11605]: Serious error during accept: Too many open files
```

until i press ctrl+C.

this is the cntlm.conf i have:

```
#
# Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration
#
# NOTE: all values are parsed literally, do NOT escape spaces,
# do not quote. Use 0600 perms if you use plaintext password.
#

Username    myUsername
Domain      localhost
Password    password
# NOTE: Use plaintext password only at your own risk
# Use hashes instead. You can use a "cntlm -M" and "cntlm -H"
# command sequence to get the right config for your environment.
# See cntlm man page
# Example secure config shown below.
# PassLM          1AD35398BE6565DDB5C4EF70C0593492
# PassNT          77B9081511704EE852F94227CF48A793
### Only for user 'testuser', domain 'corp-uk'
# PassNTLMv2      D5826E9C665C37C80B53397D5C07BBCB

# Specify the netbios hostname cntlm will send to the parent
# proxies. Normally the value is auto-guessed.
#
# Workstation   netbios_hostname

# List of parent proxies to use. More proxies can be defined
# one per line in format <proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
#

Listen      127.0.0.1:3128
#Listen     192.168.0.1:3128

#Proxy      10.0.0.41:8080
#Proxy      10.0.0.42:8080
Proxy       127.0.0.1:3128

# List addresses you do not want to pass to parent proxies
# * and ? wildcards can be used
#
NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*

# Specify the port cntlm will listen on
# You can bind cntlm to specific interface by specifying
# the appropriate IP address also in format <local_ip>:<local_port>
# Cntlm listens on 127.0.0.1:3128 by default
#

# If you wish to use the SOCKS5 proxy feature as well, uncomment
# the following option. It can be used several times
# to have SOCKS5 on more than one port or on different network
# interfaces (specify explicit source address for that).
#
# WARNING: The service accepts all requests, unless you use
# SOCKS5User and make authentication mandatory. SOCKS5User
# can be used repeatedly for a whole bunch of individual accounts.
#
SOCKS5Proxy 5000
#SOCKS5User username:password

# Use -M first to detect the best NTLM settings for your proxy.
# Default is to use the only secure hash, NTLMv2, but it is not
# as available as the older stuff.
#
# This example is the most universal setup known to man, but it
# uses the weakest hash ever. I won't have it's usage on my
# conscience. :) Really, try -M first.
#
#Auth       LM
#Flags      0x06820000

# Enable to allow access from other computers
#
#Gateway    yes

# Useful in Gateway mode to allow/restrict certain IPs
# Specifiy individual IPs or subnets one rule per line.
#

Allow       127.0.0.1
Deny        0/0

# GFI WebMonitor-handling plugin parameters, disabled by default
#
#ISAScannerSize     1024
#ISAScannerAgent    Wget/
#ISAScannerAgent    APT-HTTP/
#ISAScannerAgent    Yum/

# Tunnels mapping local port to a machine behind the proxy.
# The format is <local_port>:<remote_host>:<remote_port>
# 
#Tunnel     11443:remote.com:443
```

i tried many times to change configuration but it really doesn't change. If i put 127.0.0.1:3128 as default Proxy (what i am trying to do) it starts well but ends in a loop.

what should i do to make it works and where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `ulimit -n`?

Comment: I think you are better off asking this on [sf], let me close this for you.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a shot, ty!

Answer (score 1):

please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348)

It is obvious you will get loop with this configuration! you kept your Listen and proxy port the very same!So whatever it listens it proxies to self and it is cumulative!

**Enter windows proxy server name and port in Proxy! not your local host!**

```
Username    Enter-your-username-here
Domain      Enter-your-domain-here
Password    Enter-your-password-here

Proxy       proxyhost:proxyport
Proxy       proxyhost:proxyport

NoProxy     localhost,127.0.0.1

Listen      3128
```

i.e. if you want maven to use cntlm, put localhost:3128 in maven settings.xml so that it would get proxy to your proxyhost:proxyport with defined domain username and passowrd.

Comment: Second link is dead https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987501/1802348 May someone with edit rights remove it ?