# cntlm keeps on prompting for password

Tags: proxy

cntlm-0.92.3-8.fc23.x86_64

cntlm -h says that I can specify password on command line

```
-p  <password>
    Account password. Will not be visible in "ps", /proc, etc.
```

but when I invoke it with

```
cntlm -H -p mypass -u myuser -d mydomain
```

it prompts me again

```
cntlm -H -u myuser -d mydomain -p mypass
Password: 
PassLM          FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
PassNT          FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 
PassNTLMv2      FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF    # Only for user 'myuser', domain 'mydomain'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with echoing the password

`echo "${PASSWD}" | cntlm -H -u ${USERNAME} -d ${DOMAIN} | grep PassNTLMv2`

Answer (score 0):

update cntlm.conf(if you are using windows cntlm.ini file) file with all parameters and then fire

Windows

```
cntlm -c cntlm.ini -I -M http://google.ro
```

Linux

```
cntlm -c cntlm.conf -I -M http://google.ro
```

If you want guidance regarding CNTLM configuration,

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348) answer for windows

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987501/1802348) answer for linux

Comment: @AleksandrKostyrev please share your cntlm.conf file.I did not get why you do not set cntlm proxy server as default proxy for your system! why you need to execute cntlm.exe from terminal?

Comment: you got me wrong. I'm not executing cntlm from terminal to use it. I was looking for a way to config cntlm. see https://github.com/kostyrevaa/workstation/blob/master/kick_the_automation.sh#L125