# Fail DL jars Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After 2 weeks searching different solutions : i failed to find an answer : here the stack of error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-samples/3.0.7.RE
LEASE/spring-security-samples-3.0.7.RELEASE.pom
fÚvr. 24, 2016 5:22:53 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator generate
AuthResponse
AVERTISSEMENT: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credent
ials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
fÚvr. 24, 2016 5:22:53 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator generate
AuthResponse
AVERTISSEMENT: KERBEROS authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find an
y Kerberos tgt)
fÚvr. 24, 2016 5:22:53 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator generate
AuthResponse
AVERTISSEMENT: NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.maven.
wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.996 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-24T17:22:53+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TestProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project TestProject:T
estProject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.security:spring-security-s
amples:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.security:spring-security-s
amples:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-samples:pom:
3.0.7.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Pr
oxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Pr
oxy filter is denied.  ). -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I'm using Eclipse Mars , Maven 3.3.3 and i configured the `settings.xml` with a proxy.

I also tried to use ISA Firewall with no success. Is it possible that the antivirus Symantec EndPoint can deny the DL ?

Thnx

**EDIT**
settings.xml :

```
 <proxies>
  <proxy>
     <id>proxy</id>
     <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <host>172.22.200.22</host>
     <port>8080</port>
     <username>INTRA\USerName</username>                                                
     <password>password</password>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Configuration Eclipse Pictures :

[image: Window -> Referencs -> General -> Network Connection]

[image: Logs Errors]

Any suggestion is the welcome

Comment: you access the internet via a proxy, you need to provide authentication?

Comment: the company uses proxy configured in the computer. And in the `settings.xml` i configured the authentication with the name of my session and the password

Comment: @JPMoresmau i edit with my  `settings.xml`

Comment: You have kerberos in play...Apart from that you should use the internal repository manager in your company instead of maven central...

Comment: @khmarbaise thnx for the reply, i want to configure Nexus OSS in this company because they have'nt already , and to configure Nexus i have to configure the proxy to copy the jars existing in the ~/.m2 to Nexus and it's not possible without configuring proxy

Answer (score 0):

For to reduce possible issues,Do not use embedded maven installation of eclipse.

Download maven binaries from official website and configure maven installation for NTLM proxy.You need CNTLM to take away these NTLM problems.Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348) tutorial it is very detailed one.After you done with successful maven installation by using command prompt, just add that installation to eclipse by changing preferences.

Tip: many times eclipse do not even open maketplace even we entered all proxy details in preferences.Just point your system proxy to CNTLM proxy port and you will be able to access marketplace.

Comment: Hi, it's not the solution, the problem was TMG Forefront which blocked the acess, the link that you mentioned : i tried it and it didn't resolve the problem